# The readystate property of the XMLHttpRequest is editable or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is the `readyState` property of the XMLHttpRequest editable?

```
function myFunction() { 
    loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt", function() {   
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }   
    }); 
 }
```

Here can I customize the values for `status==200` or `readyState==4`?

Comment: Can you explain what/why you want to do that? They are set based on the response received from the server ...

Comment: By "*editable*", you mean "settable" or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in XMLHttpRequest [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), these attributes are read-only:

```
readonly attribute unsigned short readyState;
readonly attribute unsigned short status;
```

You can't modify them.